# angular js watch ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have an array that I use in view with `ng-repeat`. After that every 10 sec I update that array and my values are changed in the interface. I want to be able to call a function `$scope.alertFunction` when one value is updated.

For example I have one field with value `0`, when the array is updated, this field will have value `1`, and on interface I'll see `1` instead `0`, in that moment I want to trigger this function `alertFunction`. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you can watch the array like so:

```
$scope.$watch('myArray', function(){
    //something happenned
}, true);
```

Comment: Should still work. Paste the code for how your array updates.

Answer (score 0):

That should all be done in your controller, so don't worry about the ng-repeat.

Watches are incredibly useful, but they can also be expensive because they are executed every digest, whenever *anything* changes in your scopes.

Also, if you put a watch on the whole array then it won't tell you which elements have changed, only that *something* has.

In this case, the code that updates your array is something you have control over, so you don't need a separate watch, you should be able to check for changes at the time you update it.

For example:

```
function updateItems(newItems) {
    $scope.items.forEach(function(obj, i) {
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(f) {
            var oldValue = obj[f];
            var newValue = newItems[i][f];
            if(newValue !== oldValue) {
                $scope.alertFunction({
                    index: i,
                    field: f,
                    oldValue: oldValue,
                    newValue: newValue
                });
            }
        });
    });
    $scope.items = newItems; // assuming you don't mind the array ref changing
}
```

**Edited** to work with your example.

Answer (score 0):

So I have an array

$scope.items = [{field_first: 0, field_sec: 1},{field_first: 1, field_sec: 3},{field_first: 0, field_sec: 0}]

After 10 seconds I'll have

$scope.items = [{field_first: 0, field_sec: 1},{field_first: 1, field_sec: 3},{field_first: 1, field_sec: 0}]

In this case it has been update $scope.items[2]["field_first"] instead of 0 it has value 1 now. I want to trigger the event for this field.